# Java Kerberos authentication: get user groups from ticket using spring security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, spring-security-kerberos

I need to implement Kerberos authentication and get AD user groups for the authenticated user. I am restricted to use Kerberos protocol only so I am not able to use LDAP queries to AD.
It looks like, Kerberos authentication could be implemented using Spring security, but retrieving groups is not so simple.
According to the [How to retrieve group membership from a kerberos ticket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263961/how-to-retrieve-group-membership-from-a-kerberos-ticket) and [Get AD Groups with kerberos ticket in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20152000/get-ad-groups-with-kerberos-ticket-in-java), there is no native support in Java reading the PAC fields.
Update: it looks like there is PACdecoder in the http://jaaslounge.sourceforge.net/.
Is there any spring-security antive solution to get roles or should I use external classes?